# Regex pattern doesn't work when ending without a space

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove strings that contain either http or https. I have the following code segment:

```
    String line="abc http://someurl something https://someurl";

    if (line.contains("https") || line.contains("http")) {
        System.out.println(line);
        String x = line.replaceAll("https?://.*?\\s+", " ");
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

The output is: `abc  something https://someurl` (doesn't remove the ending url)

Desired output is: `abc  something`

I'm guessing its a simple change to the regex...

Edit: Sorry, the previous example didn't contain an actual url after the http.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is

```
https?://.*?\\s+
```

That final token `\s+` means *one or more space characters*. If you want to remove substrings that *don't* necessarily end in spaces, you can repeat with `*` instead of `+` - `*` means to repeat the preceding token *zero or more times*:

```
String x = line.replaceAll("https?://.*?\\s*", " ");
```

That said, if the URLs you have are valid and don't contain any space characters, it would probably make more sense to match non-space characters with `\S` and replace with the empty string, rather than look for space characters, match them, and then replace with *another* space:

```
String x = line.replaceAll("https?://\\S*", "");
```

Comment: Sorry, my previous input didn't have the actual URL after http. I would like the whole URL removed..

Comment: @kami `https?://[^\\s]*\\s*`

Comment: @TuyenPham Much better to use `\S` than `[^\s]`

Comment: @CertainPerformance, yes it is, I don't see your last comment when I write mine, and the `\S` doesn't popup in my brain :)